# regex to return characters in position 3-4

Tags: regex, ansible

Given string

```
1201-ryryryry
```

I want to extract `01`, only characters in position `3-4`

With https://regex101.com/

I can regex

```
^(?:.{2})(.{2})
```

Which returns:
Full match  0-4 `1201`
Group 1.    2-4 `01`

Using Ansible `regex_search()` and it appears it only reads the "Full match" of 1201.

Any idea how I can have it match only 01?

Answer (score 0):

> Using Ansible `regex_search()`

Do you want to simply get a substring? Why would you use a regular expression filter for that?

Use regular [Python slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2947502) in Jinja2 template:

```
string[x:y]
```

`x` points to the position from which to include; `y` points to the position from which to cut off -- in your case to get `01` (you can, of course, use a variable instead of the string directly):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ '1201-ryryryry'[2:4] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Positive LookBehind

```
(?<=\d{2})\d{2}
```